# Testing Vuetify with Vue-test-utils - Cannot set value to v-text-field

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, testing, vuetify.js, vue-test-utils

I want to test simple login form with two v-text-fields and one v-btn. I'm testing with Jest and Vue test utils.

Code looks like that:

```
<v-text-field
    v-model="form.email"
    test-id="input-email">
</v-text-field>
```

My test looks like that:

```
import Login from './login.vue'
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'

describe('login', () => {
  it('set value', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Login)
    const emailInput = wrapper.findComponent('[test-id="input-email"]')
    emailInput.setValue('john@example.com')
  })
})
```

And I'm getting error:

> [vue-test-utils]: wrapper.setValue() cannot be called on this element

and points here:
`emailInput.setValue('john@example.com')`

How can I set value to v-text-field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to repeat your example and it works

Component:

```
<template>
  <v-text-field
    v-model="form.email"
    test-id="input-email"
  />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      form: { email: '' },
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Test:

```
import Input from './input.vue'
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'

describe('input', () => {
  it('should set v-model', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Input)
    const input = wrapper.findComponent('[test-id="input-email"]')
    input.setValue('test')
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks Igor! My problem was that I was using shallowMount instead of mount. Now it is working.